# How do I automatically determine the size of each sprite in a spritesheet

Tags: rust, bevy

I have multiple sprite sheets but each one has slightly smaller/larger sprites (oops)
But they all luckily have a very well defined border (though it is a different size for each sheet)

I want to be able to detect how large each sprite sheet's sprites are in order to properly turn them into separate image handles

I tried just hard coding the separate sizes but it was too clunky and not scalable. I also saw this post: [Sprite Sheet Detect Individual Sprite Bounds Automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584586/sprite-sheet-detect-individual-sprite-bounds-automatically), but the answers are for splitting a sprite sheet into individual images, so I'm not sure if it applies

Image of one of the [sprite sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfCpm.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: usually there is a trick pixels color in first row/colum for that (?)