# What is thresh in this statement?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to do the equivalent in c++ of some code written in python.

In the following link:

[How to automatically detect and crop individual sprite bounds in sprite sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584586/how-to-automatically-detect-and-crop-individual-sprite-bounds-in-sprite-sheet)

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

The output of threshold is a Mat. What is thresh ? The convention in c++ is different, because there is no subscript operator for Mat in opencv c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is [`cv::threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57). It has various types of *thresholding*, one being `Otsu`'s thresholding. This is automatic thresholding, which returns two things: the thresholded (binary) image and the selected threshold. OpenCV C++ functions normally return their results by reference, so you must supply the output matrix. In this case, the function also returns the threshold value as a `double`. The equivalent code in C++ should be something like this:

```
cv::Mat binaryImage; // Output matrix
double threshold = cv::threshold(gray, binaryImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv::THRESH_OTSU);
```

The results in python are packed in a two-element tuple. The first element `[0]` is the threshold value while the second `[1]` element is the binary image.

Answer (score 1):

In Python/OpenCV, the second return value for cv2.threshold() is the output image -- the thresholded, binary result.

Please read the documention at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57 and https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html.

The first return value is the threshold that was used.

Your equation ends with [1].  So thresh is just the output, thresholded image.