# How to detect and crop individual sprites when their bounding boxes overlap?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, sprite

Please refer to this link first:

[How to automatically detect and crop individual sprite bounds in sprite sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584586/how-to-automatically-detect-and-crop-individual-sprite-bounds-in-sprite-sheet)

In the example in the above link, the bounding boxes of the individual sprites do not overlap, so the code in the accepted answer works well, and all the sprites are extracted in individual files.

[image: Non-overlapping bounding boxes sprite sheet]

But supposed the sprites were packed differently such that their bounding boxes overlapped even thought the individual images did not overlap:

[image: Overlapping bounding boxes sprite sheet]

Then the above code would not work well at all, and just one file is output because the bounding boxes would intersect.

How would someone solve this problem using OpenCV?

Without using OpenCV, my approach would be to:

- Iterate through each sprite till I found a non-transparent sprite. Store it, and all connected non-transparent sprites as an individual set.
- Once no more connected pixels from the previous set, examine the remaining pixels in the rest of the image, ignoring the ones I have already seen and put in the above set. When I encounter a new non-transparent pixel I have not seen before, then repeat the same as the first step, but place these connected pixels in a new set.
- Like that repeat the process till there are no pixels left to examine.
- For each set of connected pixels, create a new image with the dimensions from a bounding box constructed by the farthermost pixels of that set. But include only the pixels from that connected set in the output image. Repeat for each set to create a new image for each connected set.

Instead of the approach I have described above, is there a method to use OpenCV to do this ? I can do it using my method, but I would like to learn more about OpenCV and what it is capable of, but I am just a beginner and still learning.

Comment: How about this: create a binary mask of the entire sprite sheet like in the original answer. Make sure the actual sprites do not overlap. Now, for each binary blob in the binary mask get its external contour and centroid. Draw the (white) contour in a new black image, same size as the sprite sheet, at the same location of the current sprite. Fill the contour. This is your new sprite mask. `AND` this mask and the original sprite sheet, this will "erase" all sprites except the one you are currently processing. Crop/save this image instead, as it will only contain the sprite of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill each contour with white and then generate an image with only that contour. After that, apply a regular cropping by getting the properties of the bounding rect. Here is the code:

```
im = cv2.imread("trees.png") # read image
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imGray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # contouring
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sorting, not necessary...
for contourIdx in range(0,len(sortedContours)-1): # loop with index for easier saving
    contouredImage = im.copy() # copy image
    contouredImage = cv2.drawContours(contouredImage, sortedContours, contourIdx, (255,255,255), -1) # fill contour with white
    extractedImage = cv2.inRange(contouredImage, (254,254,254), (255,255,255)) # extract white from image
    resultImage = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask=extractedImage) # AND operator to get only one filled contour at a time
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(sortedContours[contourIdx]) # get bounding box
    croppedImage = resultImage[y:y + h, x:x + w] # crop
    cv2.imwrite("contour_"+str(contourIdx)+".png", croppedImage) # save
```

And the results look nice as well, I'll just post the biggest one and smallest one as an example:

[image: Biggest tree]

[image: Smallest]

**V2.0**: make it work with both images

The first image, for some reason, has 255 on the green channel for all the background. Which is why only one big contour is detected. I added a few lines of code to pre-process the image and also to take into consideration the alpha channel. Here is the code:

```
im = cv2.imread("trees.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # read image
b, g, r, alpha = cv2.split(im.copy()) # split image
g[g==255] = 0 # for the first image where the green channel has 255 on all background pixels
imBGR = cv2.merge([b,g,r]) # recombine image in BGR format
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(imBGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # convert to gray
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imGray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # contouring
sortedContours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True) # sorting, not necessary...
for contourIdx in range(0,len(sortedContours)-1): # loop with index for easier saving
    contouredImage = imBGR.copy() # copy BGR image
    contouredImage = cv2.drawContours(contouredImage, sortedContours, contourIdx, (255,255,255), -1) # fill contour with white
    extractedImage = cv2.inRange(contouredImage, (254,254,254), (255,255,255)) # extract white from image
    resultImage = cv2.bitwise_and(imBGR, imBGR, mask=extractedImage) # AND operator to get only one filled contour at a time
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(sortedContours[contourIdx]) # get bounding box
    croppedImage = resultImage[y:y + h, x:x + w] # crop
    cv2.imwrite("trees_2_contour_"+str(contourIdx)+".png", croppedImage) # save
```

I won't bother with adding images of the results again, as they are the same as before. However, here is an image of the first example with the green background I am talking about:

The code:

```
im = cv2.imread("trees2.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) # read image
b, g, r, alpha = cv2.split(im.copy()) # split image
imBGR = cv2.merge([b,g,r]) # recombine image in BGR format
plt.imshow(imBGR)
```

The image:

[image: Example]

I went around this with `g[g==255] = 0`

Comment: This worked perfectly in the case of the image where the bounding boxes were overlapping, but seemed to fail with the image where the bounding boxes were not overlapping. I can't understand why.

Comment: Also just curious, why the background is black instead of transparent like the original ?

Comment: @RahulIyer Tino [read](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) the image with the default `IMREAD_COLOR` flag, which converts the input image to `BGR` color image, discarding the alpha (transparency) mask. The bitwise AND rendered all non-white pixels black, such as the background.

Comment: I usually always read with `RGB` to be able to plot in matplotlin. Anyway, is the answer not working? what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @TinoD it works for the second image where the bounding boxes are overlapping. But in the case where the bounding boxes are not overlapping (first image), then it just outputs the original image.

Comment: oh okay, let me check it and i'll get back to you

Comment: @RahulIyer for some reason the first image has a background which is mainly 255 on the green channel and 0 on the r and b channels. Any explanation?

Comment: Reading it with the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` gives a better representation for both images. I will edit the code with these changes

Comment: @TinoD - no idea why it has 255 on the green channel. Its just a random image I picked from some other questions here on stack overflow because it seemed useful.

Comment: @RahulIyer can you still accept the answer?

Comment: @TinoD yup, I did.